# How to call python script in different directory using subprocess?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to run a program located at
`/Users/*/Downloads/Mood Script Static` and another located a folder deeper at `/Users/*/Downloads/Mood Script Static Edit/LowMood_Static`. Now I am trying to invoke a subprocess controller that will run two python scripts, like this:

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'SubjectSFbalance.py']) 
print("\n")
time.sleep(0.5)
subprocess.call(['python3', 'LowMood_Static/LowMoodZScoring.py'])
```

However, when running the 2nd process, it correctly finds the .py script, but pandas cannot read the .csv files that are given in the LowMoodZScoring.py file, which is this:

```
Normalized_Subj = pd.read_csv('../SF_Output_Files/finished_sf_balance.csv')

giving the following error: 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../SF_Output_Files/finished_sf_balance.csv'
```

However, when I run LowMoodZScoring.py without using the subprocess, I get no such error.  What in subprocess is causing this error?

Comment: set the `cwd` arg (may need to use `subprocess.Popen`) to choose a working directory or set the script to accept a path argument (so it can be directly given the path to its input csv)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, since those CSV paths are relative, it looks like you need to add `cwd="LowMood_Static"` to the parameters of your subprocess call, so that it will run with that directory as the working directory.

To avoid this in a more comprehensive/future-proof way, it would be even better to have your LowMoodZScoring.py script load the CSV files relative to the directory of that script (i.e. `os.path.dirname(__file__)`), instead of relative to the current working directory.